# ¿Por que se ejecuta 3 veces el programa?

Tags: java, java-swing

No tengo mucho programando, realice una aplicación grafica y corre bien, el problema es que se ejecuta 3 veces, en la aplicación se pide la entrada a solo 10 números y el ciclo se cierra, aun así la aplicación pide 30 números, anexo el código de la clase del main y el código de la clase

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.security.*;
 
public class FigurasAlAzar extends JPanel 
{
     // Usando la Clase SecureRandom se generaran los valores aleatorios
    SecureRandom numerosAleatorios = new SecureRandom();
    
    private static final int OVALO = 1;
    private static final int RECTANGULO = 2;
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
       
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        int seleccion = 1;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Asigna un color aleatorio
            g.setColor(new Color(numerosAleatorios.nextInt(256), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(256), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(256)));
            
            // Manda a llamar al metodo lecturaOpcion, el usuario introduce el numero
            seleccion = lecturaOpcion(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba 1 para un Ovalo o 2 para un Rectangulo"));  
            switch (seleccion)
            {
                case OVALO:
                    // Hace un ovalo en una posicion aleatoria
                    g.fillOval(numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getWidth()), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getHeight()), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getWidth()/2), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getHeight()/2));
                    break;
                case RECTANGULO:
                    // Hace un rectangulo en una posicion aleatoria
                    g.fillRect(numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getWidth()), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getHeight()), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getWidth()/2), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getHeight()/2));
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero no entra en el rango");
                    i--;
                    break;
            }
        }
}
    // Metodo para leer la opcion del usuario
    public int lecturaOpcion(String opcionUsuario)
    {
        int opcion; 
        try 
        {
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(opcionUsuario);//convierte entrada en int
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El caracter introducido es incorrecto");
            opcionUsuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Favor de escribir 1 para ovalo o 2 para rectangulo");
            try 
            {
                opcion = Integer.parseInt(opcionUsuario);
            } 
            catch (NumberFormatException f)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tu estas pe*****, ¿verdad?");
                opcion = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(2) + 1;
            }
        }
         return opcion;
    }
}

public class PruebaFigurasAlAzar 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FigurasAlAzar panel = new FigurasAlAzar();
        JFrame aplicacion = new JFrame();
        
        aplicacion.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        aplicacion.add(panel);
        aplicacion.setSize(230, 250);
        aplicacion.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Ya lo eh revisado e incluso le puse un contador extra en el metodo *paintComponent* para revisar si era que el ciclo *for* el cual se bucleaba, sigo sin encontrar el error en la clase que tengo el main tampoco encuentro errores, no se si alguien me pueda indicar en que estoy mal o que es lo que hice mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema específicamente es que el bucle que pinta las figuras esta dentro del método `paintComponent`, este método se llama siempre que algo se AGREGA al panel o siempre que cambie la ventana de tamaño, mas bien, siempre que los gráficos se tengan que actualizar.

Este bucle se repite 10 veces, y se muestra en cada interacción un `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, pero a la vez que una figura se repinta, se vuelve a llamar al método por lo que puede dar algunos fallos a la otra de mostrar la ventana de opciones para pintar.

La idea que se me ocurrió para solucionar esto, es que tengas una `List` que almacene los números que se vayan a pintar en el panel y que tengas un método para poder llenar esta lista al principio.

Algo así quedaría el código, lo modifique un poquito:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.security.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FigurasAlAzar extends JPanel 
{

    private static final int OVALO = 1;
    private static final int RECTANGULO = 2;

    private SecureRandom numerosAleatorios = new SecureRandom(); // Clase  SecureRandom para numeros aleatorios.
    private ArrayList<Integer> figuras = new ArrayList<>(); // Se guardan las opciones de figuras a dibujar.

    private int FIGURAS_MAXIMAS = 10; // Cuantas figuras se van a pintar

    public void dibujar() {
        for (int i = 0; i < FIGURAS_MAXIMAS; i++) {
            figuras.add(lecturaOpcion("Escriba 1 para un Ovalo o 2 para un Rectangulo"));
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < figuras.size(); i++) {
            g.setColor(new Color(numerosAleatorios.nextInt(256), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(256), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(256)));
        
            switch(figuras.get(i)) {
                case OVALO:
                    // Hace un ovalo en una posicion aleatoria
                    g.fillOval(numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getWidth()), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getHeight()), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getWidth()/2), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getHeight()/2));
                    break;
                case RECTANGULO:
                    // Hace un rectangulo en una posicion aleatoria
                    g.fillRect(numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getWidth()), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getHeight()), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getWidth()/2), numerosAleatorios.nextInt(getHeight()/2));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    
    }

    public int lecturaOpcion(String mensaje) {
        String entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mensaje);
        int opcion = 0;
    
        try {
        
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada); // Convierte la entrada a INT
        
            if(opcion < 1 || opcion > 2) { // Si se pasa de 1 o 2
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero no entra en el rango");
                return lecturaOpcion("Escriba 1 para un Ovalo o 2 para un Rectangulo");
            }
        
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El caracter introducido es incorrecto");
       
            try {
                opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Favor de escribir 1 para ovalo o 2 para rectangulo"));
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tu estas pe*****, ¿verdad?");
                opcion = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(2) + 1;
            }
        
        }
    
        return opcion;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame aplicacion = new JFrame();
        aplicacion.setTitle("Title");
        aplicacion.setSize(500, 500);
        aplicacion.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        aplicacion.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
        FigurasAlAzar panel = new FigurasAlAzar();
        aplicacion.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
        aplicacion.setVisible(true);
    
        panel.dibujar();
    }

}
```

Si queres que las figuras no se muestren hasta que se hallan seleccionado todas las opciones solo saca la llamada de `repaint()` del método `dibujar()`.

Vuelvo aclarar que mientras se agregue algo nuevo al panel, el método `paintComponent` se llamara, por lo que las figuras pintadas anteriormente cambiaran de posición y tamaño si estas no se guardan en alguna clase, por ejemplo una clase llamada `Figura` que guarde la posición, tamaño y color.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, no pensé en utilizar una `List` dado que quería "solucionarlo con lo que se" hasta el momento, pero realmente es una gran respuesta el guardar las figuras que se van a pintar me ayudo mucho, te agradezco.